# Excel spreadsheet to COBOL program

Tags: excel, cobol, mainframe, jcl, vba

I have a task to migrate an Excel Macro(Which basically does screen scraping) to a COBOL program.

Problem is that the user wants to give the input in excel format , I am stumped as to how to convert an excel file as a readable input to a TN3270 Mainframe system.

Some have suggested to do something called as flat file conversion which I am not sure how to do.

Is there a easier method to extract inputs from an Excel spreadsheet to run a COBOL program on a TN3270 Mainframe.

The below is the screenshot of the tool which is to be converted.

[image]

According to my knowledge, we can convert it into a flat file and read the strings using delimiter(|) but I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Good luck. The excel macro api is very weak. In particular using something like cobal to get through it. The only tip I can offer is that xlsx files are zipped xml files.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. You need a lot more, accurate, informaiton. TN3270 is just a hardware-emulation term. Need to know where, and on what OS and with which compiler, the COBOL program is going to be. Also need to know exactly any continuing role of the Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: The downvote is probably because you have not provided sufficient information. It's a tough one. If you can work it into a good question, I'll offset the downvote for you with my upvote. But my first thought is that reading between the lines, someone in the design process has expectations beyond the reasonable. Describe exactly what is happening now, and exactly what you hope to replace it withj.

Comment: @ Bill .Thanks , I am not much familiar on the Mainframe part since we use the emulator(TN3270) but I know its running the Z/Os i have no idea about the compiler, the excel file will be  treated only as pure input nothing more.

Comment: Need a lot more, like how often will the spreadsheet be the source (once, once a day, some other period)? You will be using Enterprise COBOL, does your site have CICS, IMS/DC? What DBMS, if any? Is there any return of data to the spreadsheet? Will the user end up using a Mainframe system which they'd like to look a bit more like Excel than would be normal? It can be done, but can't be anywhere near the power oif Excel.

Comment: Nice question: Yes we have access to CICS but we dont want to use it, the database is IMS. The excel will be accessed based on request and not a schedule, The user is supposed to run a particular job (JCL job) which will use this excel file as a data source to update the IMS database.

Comment: OK, you need to edit that into the question. With the update of the IMS database, will it be a simple replacement of everything, or something else? Why don't you want to use CICS? How else does the designer think you're going to run a COBOL program which intereacts with the user in a reasonable way (offereing a window on their row/column data)? How will the data be used othewise on the Mainframe (other than the user who wants to see it like a spreadsheet)?

Comment: What automation package do you have on your mainframe (Control-O, etc.) ?  What file transfer options are available (FTP, SFTP, FTPS, etc.) ?  You say you "are not much familiar on the Mainframe part" - I'm afraid that in order to solve this problem you must become more familiar.

Comment: Ok.. The reason why we  want to avoid CICS is because the user does not have mainframe knowledge at all, at present he is filling up the excel macro with data and running it , the macro does screen scraping and executes the function through the CICS screen and provides an output to the user, What we want to do is to retain the excel user input but instead of using a CICS screen , we want to manually access the IMS DB(which the macro cant) and update the segments with the Business logic.

Comment: @cschneid we can do FTP. I dont think we have any automation.

Comment: For your chosen route, don't even consider re-writing Excel in COBOL. If the data is just referenced on the Mainframe, push it towards IMS out of Excel, If it is updated on the Mainframe, you need to periodically push the data back from the Mainframe. You need good thought and controls around the files so that you can be sure the correct file (date and environment and containing all records) is used wherever it is used. This is interim solution. If the data has any importance, ensure compliance, regulatory, accounting and audit are happy.The scope for foot-shooting is immense, so do it well.

Comment: As @cschneid implied, you almost certainly will have automation products available (on your Windows, and on the Mainfame). Without using those, you'll be making even stiffer the rod you will make for your own back, as it were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to split your task in several steps

1. Extract data from Excel sheet
2. Make data available to COBOL program
3. Work with data in COBOL

Not knowing the details of your problem I can only suggest solutions at this point:

1. Use Visual Basic for applications to create a file (you might want to look for a CSV solution and take into account that it might be necessary to change the file encoding)
2. Use a transfer utility - e.g. ftp or some other mainframe connection that let's you transfer files from the Excel-running computer to the mainframe. Some 3270 terminal software also offers APIs for this.
3. Convert Excel logic to COBOL (if any)

Comment: Wow.. Spot on! this is what we have figured out to do .. and we are doing it, we tried SOAP for transfer but simple FTP worked.. Can you just give a tip on how to use the .csv file so that COBOL code can read it, i mean there are different columns right , currently we are using a delimiter to know when a particular field ends and so on..

Comment: Although other answers were useful, but my current scenario this was SPOT ON ... thank you.. would be really glad if you could help me get through this.

Comment: Thanx. An internet search is you friend. E.g. "cobol read comma delimited file" gives a few results. One of them is http://www.simotime.com/cblcsv02.htm

Comment: @Anarach That comes under number five, Roll Your Own. The particular way you have chosen is what I dismiss in my opening paragraph. Make really, really, really, sure your user is going to be OK moving from Excel that they know, to a home-written Mainframe system (so no scrolling by mouse, no forumlas, no cell-locking, no formatting for print, no copy/paste out of or into with large areas or with formatted data, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc). If you complete  "Convert Excel logic to COBOL (if any)" within your lifetime, let me know and I'll upvote your question.

Comment: @BillWoodger I understand that, Mainframes cannot reaplace excel but the issue is that we are dealing with a lot of sensitive data and in excel the users are making silly mistakes which is costing company millions so we are going to retain the excel for input functionality and convert the business logic into COBOL program. we will teach the user how to run a JCL program and train them on mainframes.

Comment: @Anarach can you update your question please with this information? The "screen-scraping" part has never been clear. There's an implication that the spreadsheet is accessing data from the Mainframe, is that so? Then you have two legs to the thing. Talk to the Mainframe Scheduler team. They will tell you how they want that interaction which you think is "user runs some JCL". That is not going to happen in Production, for sure. About five departments will bounce it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run Excel on the Mainframe and to code something there would increase in complexity each time the user required more Excel-like functionality. It would be a variation of reinventing-the-wheel, which is something to avoid.

You have a user using Excel, the information is required in an IMS database on the Mainframe. By far the most sensible thing to do would be to provide something to link the two together, allowing the user to continue with Excel but with a customisation (for that specific Excel application) to connect to the IMS database and use it, even for update.

How you go about this depends on what you have at your site already with which you can do this. Here's an article from the Mainframe Edition of IBMSystems Magazine: http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/mainframe/administrator/ims/imstm_integration/

Here is an extract from the article, showing you some groups of options to do this. Within the groups, there would be specific ways to apply each option. Under RYO, of course, there are a plethora of highly-customised possibilities:

> 1. Java EE Connector Architecture (JCA)
>
> A Java-based technology solution for connecting application servers
>   and enterprise information systems (EIS), with a standard set of
>   system-level contracts between the Java EE application server and a
>   resource adapter that manage the connection, transactions, security,
>   work, life cycle, transaction inflow and message inflow.
>
> You have an existing Java EE server or one of the IBM servers that
>   needs access to IMS.
>
> Primary use is direct synchronous IMS access.
>
> 2. Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)
>
> A protocol that allows heterogeneous applications to discover and
>   communicate with each other in a platform- and language-independent
>   way.
>
> You need to interact with partners or applications that require the
>   SOAP protocol.
>
> Primary use is synchronous IMS access.
>
> 3. Representational State Transfer (REST)
>
> A protocol for simple Web services and efficient exchanges of data
>   through stateless applications, used in conjunction with JavaScript
>   Object Notation (JSON), a lightweight data-interchange format. JSON
>   and REST are often used in mobile applications, mashup tools or
>   automated business processes.
>
> You need mobile solutions.
>
> 4. Java Message Services (JMS)
>
> An asynchronous-based messaging interface for exchanging of data
>   between computers using messaging services in support of Java
>   programs.
>
> You have existing Java applications.
>
> You are using a Java EE/JMS-based application server.
>
> Primary use is asynchronous IMS access.
>
> 5. Roll-your-own (RYO)
>
> An approach often used when the organization already has its own
>   implementations of solutions that handle the transactions, security
>   and message flow.
>
> You have an existing in-house server that needs a simple API to
>   connect to IMS.

You need to go back to the designer, and they need to go to your Technical Support to find out what is already available for this type of connection. If there is nothing, then someone will have to do a technical review of what is available from various providers. A favourite search-engine will give hits of who those providers are.

Comment: Thanks a Ton Bill, SOAP looks promising. There is a support team which said would help us out on this. Hope it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple. Simply save your Excel file as a CSV file (comma delimited). Each field in the columns can be different in size. Then read it into a COBOL program, using the same saved name. And then simply use `UNSTRING` in COBOL to delimit the fields by ','.

In one program I read in 50,000 records from an Excel file into COBOL, sometimes 10,000 more, sometimes less. Using dynamic statements in COBOL, it automatically delimits each column from the Excel file into COBOL. I happen to use tables to store the records.

Comment: How do you read csv in cobol? How do you deal with date formats and edited data in the csv using cobol?